# Firefox Won't Open from Gnome Launcher

Tags: 18.04, firefox, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Mid day yesterday Firefox stopped working when trying to launch if from inside the Gnome 3 desktop.

Clicking the launcher icon in the dash or clicking links inside other applications like slack or discord fail to open firefox and do nothing.

Thunderbird also fails to launch the same way. This seems to only affect the Mozilla apps I have installed as all other programs are launching normally.

I tested a new user account and confirmed firefox would launch when logged in with it. I'm still able to run firefox from the terminal.

From journalctl -xe
`Jan 23 14:30:25 senjougahara org.gnome.Shell.desktop[11404]: /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`
`Jan 23 14:31:11 senjougahara thunderbird.desktop[22406]: /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you run Firefox from a terminal?

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes, I stated above I was able to run firefox in the terminal. I also just tested it with a new user and was able to run it from the launcher.

Comment: There are some comments I have seen that indicate that it might be a recently added extension, or a problematic profile.  You could try `mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla.bak` to see if creating a new profile for yourself helps.

Comment: @CharlesGreen already tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it was yarn screwing up the binaries in the path.

I had the following line in my `.profile`:

```
PATH=/home/user/.yarn/bin:$PATH
```

The directory `~/.yarn/bin` contains all the globally installed yarn binaries. Among those is also one called `which` and I think that's the one causing the problem.

So I changed the path in `.profile` to this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.yarn/bin
```

This way yarn will not override any system binaries (like `which`). So far everything seems to work fine.